# Vaadin doesn't display correct favicon when packaging JAR/WAR

Tags: vaadin, progressive-web-apps, favicon

I've packaged my app on a jar for production but I noticed the favicon isn't displaying the one I put. It's displaying the default blue icon with a white circle.

I've added a custom manifest and when inspecting element it does display all the correct info, I also added a @PWA annotation on the main class with the same info just in case, I also copied my logo on `src/main/webapp/icons` as `icon.png` for vaadin to resize it, and it does resize it but on the tab bar it still shows the default icon.

This only happens when packaging the app on a jar, if I run it from the IDE or the folder with `mvn spring-boot:run` it shows the correct icon.

Edit:

I found out that vaadin wasn't resizing my icon to a 16x16 size, so I did it and place it on `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/icons/` now it does show my custom favicon... on firefox, it still showing the default icon on chrome and this isn't supposed to happen because when I manually go to the url /icons/icon-16x16.png it shows my custom icon

Edit 2:

If I comment the @PWA annotation and use this code for setting the favicon:

```
    @Override
public void configurePage(InitialPageSettings settings) {
    settings.addInlineWithContents(
            "<link rel=\"shortcut icon\" href=\"favicon.ico\" type=\"image/x-icon\">",
            InitialPageSettings.WrapMode.NONE);
}
```

Then it works like it's supposed to, but as soon as I activate the @PWA annotation doesn't matter if I set or don't set a custom icon, it will be revert to the default icon

Edit 3:

I downloaded the spring boot starter app on `https://vaadin.com/start/v14` and just package the app to a jar and run it, and it won't it's icon but this default white circle icon, so I'm pretty sure it's not my project at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

When packaging as a JAR, you have to put the icon in `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/icons/`. What I have done is also using a tool like https://github.com/onderceylan/pwa-asset-generator to create all the assets. You can also use the `PageConfigurator` [interface](https://vaadin.com/docs/flow/advanced/tutorial-bootstrap.html) to customize the name and location of the favicon

Comment: Still not working, I put the icon.png in src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/icons/ and use the PageConfigurator interface and this method: settings.addFavIcon("icon", "icons/logo-192.png", "192x192"); and it still showing the default icon

Comment: All of this issues are happening only when packaging on a jar, you have any idea what it could be?

Comment: I edited my question, indeed it shows when placing the icon on META-INF, but only on firefox, it still shows the default icon on chrome

Comment: @ReneAlvarenga Please open your dev-tools in chrome, check the "clear cache" mark and do a ctrl-f5 reload; then check for that icon again.

Comment: Did that too many times @cfrick, it's also showing the default favicon on chrome on my phone, but as soon as I don't package the app to a jar and just run it with spring-boot:run it shows the correct icon

Comment: Edited my question again, the same thing happens with the starter spring boot app @cfrick, you may be able to check it, it doesn't display it's custom icon but this default icon and I don't know where this comes from

Comment: It seems like a bug, then. I opened this issue that you can upvote and follow: https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/8705 As a workaround, I used a tool like the one I mentioned and placed all the files in the `icons` directory. It worked. Have you tried that?

Comment: @AlejandroDuarte I've tried that and it didn't work, works running from the IDE but as soon as I package it to a JAR it shows the default icon, using both PNG with and without transparency, did you manage to package as a JAR and have the custom icon shown? Also I'm following the github